# Angular2 Router 3.0 beta 1 ( Child routes via Routerlink failed)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have taken a routing sample from Angular.io for new router example.

[Original Angular2 Routing Example](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/router/ts/plnkr.html)

I tried to understand and then made few changes for child routing.

1) In this example, They are navigating from  Crisis-List-items  to Crisis Detail via  `this.router.navigate(['/crisis-center', crisis.id]);`method.

I would like to use router link instead of Click event on each List item (like below), [Changes made in **crisis.list.component**]

```
[routerLink]="./crisis-center/" + crisis.id
```

I have also forked the plunker and made the changes. But now Crisis-Center List is not loading. [Changed Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7OdhoMANVK7HvtBnI8js?p=info)

Can any one suggest what is wrong? Is child routing does not work in new Router or routerlink usage here is wrong?

Comment: Why did you add the `.` to the route?

Comment: Because its a child route. Isn't it correct?

Comment: The Plunker is quite big and I don't know what changes you made. I haven't even found the routerLink you mention in your question yet. Have you checked the browser console? There is an error message printed (not too helpful though).

Comment: @Günter: I have only added router_directives in file app/crisis-center/crisis-list.component.ts. And replace click event with routerlink on html <li> tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CrisisListComponent` is a child route of `CrisisAdminComponent` the same as `CrisisDetailComponent`

```
export const crisisCenterRoutes: RouterConfig = [
  {
    path: 'crisis-center',
    component: CrisisCenterComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'admin',
        component: CrisisAdminComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
      },
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: CrisisDetailComponent,
        canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard]
      },
      {
        path: '',
        component: CrisisListComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

If you want to navigate to a sibling route you need to invoke it relative to the parent or root.

One of these reaches the route

```
[routerLink]=["../crisis-center",   crisis.id]
[routerLink]=["/crisis-center",     crisis.id]
[routerLink]=["../crisis-center/" + crisis.id]
[routerLink]=["/crisis-center/"   + crisis.id]
```

Comment: No it's not right. CrisisListComponent, CrisisDetailComponent and CrisisAdminComponent are child route of CrisisCenterComponent. If you go by configuration. Even if you tried changing the route it will not  work. (You can try it in my plunker)

Comment: But the `routerLink` you posted is in `CrisisListComponent` not in `CrisisAdminComponent`. The link has to work from where it is placed to.

Comment: I have changed the Routerlink to [routerLink]=crisis.id . It works now as expected. May be you can change the answer and then i can accept it as Answer.

Comment: Your Plunker still results in an error for me. Both my suggestions work in http://plnkr.co/edit/xNLUMPV22KjYadX6wxdM?p=preview

Comment: It worked in both the cases. Thank you for the help. :)